# Find files given an exact filename with mdfind

Tags: files, osx

Is there a way to ask `mdfind` to search for filenames with an exact filename ?

At some point in a pipe I have this:

```
(filenames are produced here) | while read f; do mdfind -name "$f" | grep -E "/$f";
```

I have two problems:

- if the filename contains a `+`:

  `grep: repetition-operator operand invalid`
- if the filename contains a parenthesis, the result is empty.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need any regular expressions here. Just try to search for a fixed string with grep. You can enable fixed string matching with the `-F` switch.

Given that your command line looks like

```
(filenames are produced here) | \
while read f ; \
    do mdfind -name "$f" | grep -F "/$f" ; \
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of the man page. ;)

The man page of mdfind says:

```
 -literal    Force the provided query string to be taken as a literal query string, without interpretation.
```

Without that option mdfind interprets characters like "*", "+" and "()" as regular expression.

The metadata attribute for file name is `kMDItemFSName`. So, to find a file with a specific name:

```
mdfind -literal 'kMDItemFSName = "somefile.txt"'
```

Bonus tip: You can also use `mdls /path/to/somefile.txt` to inspect the file's metadata

Comment: But is the filename a metadata attribute ?

Comment: This works:`mdfind -literal 'kMDItemFSName == .. ` but it is so slow that it is not usable. mdfind -name returns almost immediately, -literal takes easily 30 seconds on the request I tried.

Comment: @Antoine, that is weird. It should be _faster_ not to have to consider alternatives.

Comment: @vonbrand I'll have a look later - I'm currently moving a few TB of files - it may be related

Comment: @vonbrand I just tested on a non busy system and it's incredibly slow compared to mdfind -name.

Comment: `mdfind -literal ...` works well for me. It's nearly instantaneous